# Loop through multiple workbooks and copy into another existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for something somewhat complex. I have one master workbook (name: Verificari CE) and other workbooks are located in the same folder on desktop (folder name Verificari). If I can Loop through the entire .xls workbooks from that folder located on desktop named "Verificari" and copy the data from each workbook into this master workbook (Verificari CE).

Let's say I have these workbooks:

- Verificari CE (master workbook)
- Test A
- Test B
- Test C

Note: The name and the number (Test A; Test B; Test C….) of these workbooks will vary!

Here's how I need it to function:

- Copy all rows with data from Test A’s Sheet1 to Verificari CE.
- Then
  Check Test B's Sheet1 and copy all rows with data from A2, paste BELOW Campaign A's data on Verificari CE
- Then
  Check Test C's Sheet1 and copy all rows with data, paste BELOW Campaign B's data on Verificari CE

I'm sorry I can't upload an example (I work for a data-sensitive company). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Copymultiple()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim VerificariCE As Workbook
    Dim TestA As Workbook
    Dim TestB As Workbook
    Dim TestC As Workbook

    Dim maxRow As Long
    Dim maxCol As Integer

    Dim nextRow As Long

    Set VerificariCE = Workbooks("Verificari CE.xlsm")

    With VerificariCE.Sheets(2)   
        Workbooks.Open .Cells(1, 1).Value
        Set TestA = ActiveWorkbook

        Workbooks.Open .Cells(2, 1).Value
        Set TestB = ActiveWorkbook

        Workbooks.Open .Cells(2, 1).Value
        Set TestC = ActiveWorkbook
    End With

    'Comment this out if you don't want to clear existing values
    VerificariCE.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
    'Comment this out if you don't want to clear existing values

    nextRow = VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With TestA.Sheets(1)
        .Activate
        maxRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        maxCol = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(maxRow, maxCol)).Copy
    End With

    VerificariCE.Activate
    VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(nextRow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    nextRow = VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    TestA.Close

    With TestB.Sheets(1)
        .Activate
        maxRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        maxCol = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(maxRow, maxCol)).Copy
    End With

    VerificariCE.Activate
    VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(nextRow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    nextRow = VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    TestB.Close

    With TestC.Sheets(1)
        .Activate
        maxRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        maxCol = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(maxRow, maxCol)).Copy
    End With

    VerificariCE.Activate
    VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(nextRow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    nextRow = VerificariCE.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    TestC.Close

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    With VerificariCE.Sheets(1).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
        .Activate
    End With

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using select. Use object variables to point to your objects. Use DIR to read the files in your folder.

```
Sub Example()
const foldername = "Verificari"
const mastername = "Verificari CE.xlsm"
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim targetbook as workbook
Set targetbook = workbooks(mastername) 'I assume this code is in this file and it is therefore open
Dim targetsheet as worksheet
set targetsheet = worksheets(1) 'assume first sheet
Dim target as range
set target = targetsheet.range("a2")
Dim r as range
Dim s as string
s = dir(foldername & "*.xl*")  'read spreadsheet names
do while s <> ""
   if s = mastername then
   else
   set wb = workbooks.open(foldername & "\" & s)
   if not wb is nothing then
      set ws = wb.worksheets(1)
     '#########
      set r = targetsheet.range("a" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
      ws.usedrange.copy r
      '##########
      wb.close false
   end if
   end if   'missed this first time round
   s = dir()
loop
end sub
```

I can't test this so there may be typos

Comment: Error: Loop without Do on line "Loop"?

Comment: I've run the macro, but it does nothing. Even tried to run it by pressing F8 to see what it does, and nothing...:(

Comment: You'll need to edit the folder name to actually point to your folder's full path

Comment: edited the correct folder path, but now I have error 5 on line ws.UsedRange.Copy r

Comment: some help needed, please!

Comment: This is why I shouldn't try answering questions on a phone with no excel loaded - see second edit for correction

Comment: I think I got it! I just have to make some more trials with this code an d see if it does exactly what I want. Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: Last question: How can I make this line to be more dynamic, using Environ? Something like this: 'Const foldername = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Verificari\". I know that Constant expression cannot contain variable...

Comment: make foldername a variable (dim foldername as string) and then assign it the value you want (foldername = "C:\Users ... etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is a utility I have used in the past. It has a bit of a front end to let you select the files you want to merge, but it should provide you the code you're looking for. Good luck!

```
Public FirstRowUsed As Integer
Sub CreateInputFile()

Dim fs, f, s
Dim PathInfo As Variant
Dim TrueVar As Variant
Dim FileToOpen() As Variant

'screen.mousepointer = fmMousePointerHourglass
Application.Cursor = xlWait
FirstRowUsed = 3
LastRowUsed = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If LastRowUsed >= FirstRowUsed Then
  ClearSheet = MsgBox("Clear Sheet?", vbOKCancel, "Current Data will be deleted")

  If ClearSheet = 1 Then
    x = Range(Cells(FirstRowUsed, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    x = Range(Cells(FirstRowUsed, 1), Cells(FirstRowUsed, 1)).Select
    Selection.Activate
  Else
    x = MsgBox("Process Terminated, No Action Taken.", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo CreateInputFileExit
  End If
End If

TrueVar = True
FileToOpen = Application _
    .GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx,(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Select Files to Combine", , TrueVar)

On Local Error Resume Next

If UBound(FileToOpen) < 1 Then
  x = MsgBox("Process Terminated", vbOKOnly)
  GoTo CreateInputFileExit
Else
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FileInfo = fs.GetFile(FileToOpen(1))
  TargetPath = fs.GetParentFolderName(FileToOpen(1))
End If

On Local Error GoTo 0

Set PathInfo = fs.Getfolder(TargetPath)

TargetPath = PathInfo.shortpath

Application.StatusBar = False

On Local Error Resume Next

Call GetFileInfo(FileToOpen())

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
SendKeys "^{HOME}"  'Ctrl+Home

CreateInputFileExit:

  Application.Cursor = xlDefault

End Sub

Sub GetFileInfo(FileToOpen() As Variant)

Dim Row As Double
Dim FileCtr As Double
Dim ReportInterval As Double
Dim fs, f, s
Dim FileInfo As Variant
Dim Ext As String

On Local Error Resume Next

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Row = FirstRowUsed
ReportInterval = 100
FileCtr = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen)

  TotFileName = FileToOpen(i)

  DirCheck = Dir(TotFileName)
  DateOut = FileDateTime(TotFileName)
  FileLength = FileLen(TotFileName)

  If DirCheck > "" Then ' Eliminates Directory entries

    Set FileInfo = fs.GetFile(TotFileName)
    Ext = fs.GetExtensionName(TotFileName)
    Pathname = fs.GetParentFolderName(TotFileName)

    Filename = FileInfo.Name
    Cells(Row, 1) = Pathname
    Cells(Row, 2) = Filename
    Cells(Row, 3) = DateOut
    Cells(Row, 4) = FileLength
    Cells(Row, 5) = TotFileName
    Cells(Row, 6) = Ext
    Row = Row + 1
    FileCtr = FileCtr + 1


    If FileCtr Mod ReportInterval = 0 Then
      DoEvents
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Cells(Row - 1, 1).Activate 'Makes the screen change a bit so the user knows it is working
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.StatusBar = "File Names Processed so far: " & FileCtr
    End If

  End If

Next i

Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Sub MergeTheFiles()
Dim FileSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetBook As Workbook
Dim SourceBook As Workbook

FileSheetNm = "FileList"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(FileSheetNm).Activate

Set FileSheet = ActiveSheet
Set Targetworkbook = Workbooks.Add

MaxRow = FileSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Numfiles = MaxRow - 2

For i = 3 To MaxRow
  Sourcefile = FileSheet.Cells(i, 5)
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sourcefile, UpdateLinks:=3, ReadOnly:=True

  Set SourceWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
  TargetDirectory = FileSheet.Cells(i, 1)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For Each sh In SourceWorkBook.Worksheets
    ShtNm = sh.Name
    LastSheet = Targetworkbook.Worksheets.Count
    sh.Copy After:=Targetworkbook.Sheets(LastSheet)

        Set CurrSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(LastSheet + 1)
        Set TrgtSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        TrgtAddr = Cells(TrgtSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Address

    With CurrSht

        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

        lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy Destination:=TrgtSht.Range(TrgtAddr)
    End With

    CurrSht.Delete

  Next sh

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  SourceWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i


    DateOfFile = Format(Date$, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    TargetFileName = "$Date XYZ"

    TargetFileName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(TargetFileName, "$Date", DateOfFile)
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFilename:=TargetFileName, _
    fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    NewFileNameAndDir = fileSaveName
    If InStr(UCase(NewFileNameAndDir), ".XLS") = 0 Then
      If Right(NewFileNameAndDir, 1) = "." Then
        NewFileNameAndDir = NewFileNameAndDir & "xlsx"
      Else
        NewFileNameAndDir = NewFileNameAndDir & ".xlsx"
      End If
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileNameAndDir, _
        FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .MaxChange = 0.001
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False

   With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .MaxChange = 0.001
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: after it opens that box with this line "GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx,(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Select Files to Combine", , TrueVar), and I select the first .xlsx to open, then it does nothing.

Comment: So, you can select multiples on that box by clicking with ctrl+right mouse. That brings the file information back to the excel sheet. Then click the "Merge Files" button.